# transferring files with pysftp.get_r between linux and windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, pysftp

I want to recursively download files from a Linux server into a Windows desktop.
I'm using the following code:

```
import pysftp
import sys

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host="192.168.1.1", username="user", password="secret", cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.get_r ('test_sftp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\my_dir\\', preserve_mtime=False)
    sftp.close()
```

I have the encoutered the following error (while recursively copying the files):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 12, in <module>
    sftp.get_r ('teste_sftp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\my_dir\\', preserve_mtime=False)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 311, in get_r
    preserve_mtime=preserve_mtime)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 249, in get
    self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 720, in get
    with open(localpath, 'wb') as fl:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\my_dir\\test_sftp/n1/M51'
```

I understand that pysftp is trying to recreate the folder structure from the source into the destination folder, but it isn't sensible to the fact that it is working on a Windows machine and that the slashes should be backslashes.

How to work around it?

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427283/getting-a-files-from-remote-path-to-local-dir-using-sftp-in-python

Comment: @Valilutzik, I did. It seems to be a system permission problem, and also he is using a different function in paramiko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, pysftp doesn't have support for such feature.

I would recommend Python's [default FTP library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), which is already in the standard library ([batteries included](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/)). There you can call [retrbinary()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) giving the desired folder.

Comment: the default FTP library does not support sftp, or does it?

Comment: It does. @LuizAngioletti

Comment: Can you provide a source on how to use SFTP with the default FTP library? SFTP and FTP are entirely different so it does not make since for them to exist within the same library.